# Best way to do a duplicate check on 2 different Collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, database

I have a json file that I want to check if the document already exist in the database and then add a 'YES' or 'NO' on the on the 'DUPLICATE' key of the json file. Below is the my code snippet.

```
jsonFile.forEach(val => {
let dup = MyCollection.find({ $or: [ { EMAIL: val.EMAIL }, { PHONE: val.PHONE }, { FULLADDRESS: val.FULLADDRESS} ] }).fetch();

if (dup.length > 0) {
val.DUPLICATE = 'YES';
} else {
val.DUPLICATE = 'NO';
}
});
```

So the code is simple and work but my issue is that I my json file sometimes has more than 55,000 documents and it takes a long time to do the check. I tried to use aggregate but came up with almost the same results.

```
myCollection.aggregate([{$match : { $or: [ { EMAIL: EMAIL }, { PHONE: val.PHONE }, { FULLADDRESS: FULLADDRESS} ] }}]);
```

Is there a better way to do this? or any recommendations?

Comment: (1) are you indexing? (2) are your sharding?

Comment: Yes I am indexing but not sharding since the app is still in development

Comment: Is it your intent to insert the json document into the collection if it is not a dupe?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be sneaky but bear with me:

1. Create a shadow collection with the same keys `(EMAIL, PHONE, FULLADDRESS)`
2. Set each of those keys to be indexed, *unique* in MongoDB (you probably want to allow nulls as well)
3. Before you insert into your primary collection, attempt an insert into this shadow collection
4. If this insert *fails* you know one of your keys has already been used